# Adding Objects into action editor

Tags: animation

I've got a walk animation set up and posed in action mode and I'm trying to add a a new action where the character has a ball and chain around his leg, the ball and chain is a separate object with its own armature is there a way to make an action with both armatures and both objects or do i need to try another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same action with two different armatures. If they contain no bones with the same name, then the action will not collide. An action contains animation graphs with names. If the action is assigned, the graphs are associated with the correspondingly named bones.

If you assign it to the ball and chain, existing keyframes won't be removed. Once you keyframed the *ball* and *chain* bones, there will be *ball* and *chain* curves created. If the character doesn't have any bone named *ball* or *chain*, these curves won't interfere with it.